# Error while trying to install opencv

Tags: software-installation

I an trying to follow the procedure as given in the installation guide
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide_Linux
While trying do Path configuration I tried creating a opencv.conf file in  /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ containing a single line /usr/local/lib . But as soon as I save it I get error message:

```
vineet@vineet-XPS-M1530 /etc/ld.so.conf.d $ sudo gedit opencv.conf

(gedit:3765): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.L45S9V': No such file or directory

(gedit:3765): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory

(gedit:3765): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.U5FA9V': No such file or directory

(gedit:3765): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory

(gedit:3765): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.2ITB9V': No such file or directory

(gedit:3765): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory
vineet@vineet-XPS-M1530 /etc/ld.so.conf.d $
```

I am new to linux. Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are using `sudo` to open a file using a graphical text editor.

When you close `gedit`it will try to save the most recent file (the one you are editing) in to a recent edited files history. Because that file does not exist it fails.

The solution for that is to use `gksudo` which is made to open graphical applications with `sudo` rights and user configuration.

Open the file with `gksudo gedit opencv.conf` instead of `sudo gedit opencv.conf`.

Comment: if i dont use sudo then i get an error in the editor that I cannot save it

Comment: Please let me know what to type in terminal

Comment: Edited the answer for more information and steps to take.